# Initialize MapBox maps after page loads

Tags: google-maps, dom, mapbox

I am using the [MapBox JavaScript API](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.0.2/) and trying to display some maps on a tab widget.  Everything is working fine, except for the fact that when the page first loads, the maps do not load.  As soon as I interact with the map in some way like zoom in/out or drag, this causes all of the map tiles to load.

```
<div class="g12" id="mapbox" style="display:none">
<div class="widget" id="widget_tabs" style="min-height:400px;">
    <h3 class="handle">http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/</h3>
    <div class="tab">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#map-1">MapBox 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map-2">MapBox 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map-3">MapBox 3</a></li>
        </ul>            
        <script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v0.6.7/mapbox.js'></script>
        <link href='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v0.6.7/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

        <style>
            #map1 #map2 #map3 { position:absolute; }        
            #content {position: relative;}
        </style> 

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            mapbox.auto('map1', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');
            mapbox.auto('map2', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');
            mapbox.auto('map3', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');

            $('#content').css({ height: 700});
            var x = $('#mapbox'); /* cache the selector */
            $('#map1,#map2,#map3').css({ width:  x.width() * .98 });
            $('#map1,#map2,#map3').css({ height: x.height() * .75});
        });             
        </script>

        <div id="map-1">                   
            <div id='map1'></div>  
        </div>    

        <div id="map-2">
            <div id='map2'></div>  
        </div>

        <div id="map-3">
            <div id='map3'></div>  
        </div>    

    </div> <!--end of class=tab-->
</div> <!--end of widget_tabs-->
```

How can I modify this code so that the it forces the maps to load correctly after the page loads?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenLayers and MapBox** [OpenLayers.org](http://openlayers.org) is an open source JavaScript web mapping library distinguished from other alternatives, like Leaflet or Google Maps APIs, because of its huge set of components.

I spent the weekend creating sample apps by integrating OpenLayers with API's such as MapBox, WebGL etc... After all was said and done, I was extremely impressed with OpenLayers - and I plan to make use of OpenLayers in an upcoming POC/Project.

**Here is a link** to my [test harness](http://ddeloy.com/WebMappingOL2/maps/index.php). From there you can also download the code for all of the examples, too.

***and finally...AN ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION :)*** Defining an initialization JavaScript function: In my code below, I have defined a JavaScript function called initMap and invoke it by the browser to initialize the map after the page has finished loading.

```
<script>
function initMap() {
}    
</script>
//Modify the body opening tag and add an onload event attribute to it:

<body onload="initMap();"> </body>

        // Start - the actual code. See the test harness for working example
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
        function initMap(){
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
            var earth = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
                "Natural Earth",
                ["http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/
                  mapbox.natural-earth-hypso-bathy/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                 "http://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/
                  mapbox.natural-earth-hypso-bathy/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                 "http://c.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/
                  mapbox.natural-earth-hypso-bathy/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                 "http://d.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/
                  mapbox.natural-earth-hypso-bathy/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
                ],
                {
                  attribution: "Tiles &copy; <a href='http://mapbox.com/'>MapBox</a>",
                  sphericalMercator: true,
                  wrapDateLine: true,
                  numZoomLevels: 19
                 }
                 );
                  map.addLayer(earth);
                  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(105, 35).transform(
                  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), 4);
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but you are using google maps, and I am using MapBox.

Comment: Yep - my bad. I have some archived MapBox files that I will look through and compare to your implementation.